# Unable to download videos using IDM on Ubuntu

Tags: wine, youtube, idm

I have installed Wine and I have installed IDM on it. However, I do not get the link which asks me whether I want to download the video on the page which I get while using Windows. As a result, I am not able to download any video at all, especially the ones on Youtube.

Hope you can help me out with this.
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you not just use Firefox and something like [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) directly in Ubuntu? Why are you accessing YouTube via Wine?

Comment: This is not a direct answer to the question, but as it's not guaranteed that all Windows applications will work 100% under Wine, it's highly advisable to try first a Linux app that does the same job ( often much better ;-) and I can suggest jDownloader (Java app though) or FatRat in this case.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/737770/47206) how **IDM can be installed under Wine and integrated with Firefox**.

Other multithread Windows downloaders work also in Wine, like [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/download.htm) (better install the lite version), or [SoMud](http://www.somud.com/) (somewhat heavier, but which is able to search by itself videos before downloading them from different video hosts, beside being a torrent client).

You might want to consider an excellent Linux alternative: [uGet](http://ugetdm.com/) - which can be used in association with Firefox+Flashget to capture videos.

---

Comment: It actually does work, check this out : http://askubuntu.com/a/737770/497851

Comment: @Hossein - indeed. I have edited my answer above.