# Lubuntu Wine IDM set up with Chromium help needed

Tags: wine, lubuntu, chromium, idm

i'm very new to this forum and to linux. switching from Windows OS is tough at the start and i'm having few problems. i installed Lubuntu because i've old system. i totally love it but i have one major issue.

i want a download manager for Lubuntu. i searched in software centre but couldn't find any good one. so i installed Wine and some how i managed to install it correctly. after that i installed IDM successfully. but the problem starts now, when i open any download link, chromium automatically downloads itself. means it doesnot open IDM.
i installed an IDM plugin as well but still it doesnot work.

another thing i did was to manually copy download link address to IDM, and i can see the file and i click resume button but download doesnot starts.

what should i do ? any other download manager i need to try ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/344751/47206

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is possible to install and run Windows applications with Wine this should usually not be needed, and it may also lead to instabilities due to an often not 100% compatibility (see [Wine database for compatibility issues](http://appdb.winehq.org/)).

Many Windows programs have their native Linux counterparts, and I strongly recommend searching for these before we decide to give up, and use a Windows program with Wine. Ever so often you may also find that you simply do not need to install any additional application, because Ubuntu already had the best choice installed for you.

A good place for searching is the Ubuntu Software Center, but also we do have many questions here to give advice on applications to replace the Windows counterparts. For a download manager recommendation see:

- [What download managers are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32850/can-someone-recommend-a-download-manager)

You will soon find that applications provided from the Ubuntu repositories will nicely integrate with the desktop, i.e. you will easily be able to select any of these applications for standard actions such as downloading, or opening a certain file type.

This will not be the case for Wine applications. In case you really do need a Windows application for a given task we then have to [manually define a .desktop file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand) to announce this application to the system. For doing so see the following question:

- [How does one create a custom application launcher for Wine installed apps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137151/how-does-one-create-a-custom-application-launcher-for-wine-installed-apps)

Comment: Thanks alot for you reply :)
i really do understand alot better now with wine
i'm gonna try WGET now and will tell you :)

Comment: i tried Wget and its amazing. looks like a big problem solved but it is not as good as IDM. still anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want something as similar to IDM as possible then I'd suggest [Flareget](http://flareget.com/). It does the same thing as IDM.

Use this with Firefox and you can [even download videos embedded in sites](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/flareget-is-great-download-manager-for.html) like how IDM does.

I'm on my phone right now so I will edit this answer with the direct links later in the day

Comment: why people don't use Chromium too much ? Firefox, firefox everywhere. thank you for your suggestion. i will try this as well.

Comment: Don't blame me.. The developer made it so plus you can pay for the pro version which (according to the developer) bakes in with every other browser like how IDM does

Comment: @Alamgir post edit done. Hope this helps

Comment: do you now how to get somewhat older version of flareget (1.4)?

Comment: Well it should be on the flareget website. Try googling too