# Problem with IDM integration

Tags: google-chrome

I have installed the IDM in Ubuntu through Wine. When I integrate IDM with chrome I had select the "*use advanced browser integration*" in option. When I select that, a new window opens that have a problem. But I did right about the three problems.

IDM cannot engage advanced browser integration because of any of the following reasons:

1. You don't have admin rights or you didn't allow IDM helper program to execute  as admin.
2. You pressed "Cancel" button during IDM network driver installation.
3. You blocked IDM network driver startup or installation by means of the third party security or antivirus.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/344751/47206

Answer (score -1):

Set the windows version to windows 98 in the winecfg window.