# Is it possible to have multi-thread cURL with Flashgot in Ubuntu?

Tags: curl, download-speed, download-manager

I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19614133/4098390) that there is a multi-thread version of cURL downloader.

How to install it and can it be used with Flashgot?

I am not looking for other multi-thread downloaders, I already have Axel, Aria2, cURL, uGet and Wget in my flashgot list. I even have VLC there to open youtube in vlc if it strikes my fancy :) ... I just wanted to test a new option, that's all.

Comment: Wouldn't something like `aria2` be simpler?

Comment: @muru - I use aria2 also but i stumbled into this and i was curious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of uGet has cURL multi-connections built in without the need of a plugin.

http://uGetdm.com/

I know you are already aware of uGet as you stated in your question but not sure if you're aware of the latest version new cURL features.

Comment: that is the best solution for what I was asking; curl multi-connection inside uGet, and uGet integration in Flashgot

Comment: to change the default settings (number of connections per download, download folder, etc): [here on the uGet website](http://ugetdm.com/documentation/tutorials/21-changing-the-default-download-locationfolder)

Comment: although people seem to praise aria2 before curl, using curl multiple connections in uGet it is for the first time in Linux (maybe excepting Flareget, now very limited in the free version) that I have seen download speeds pushed up in the same way IDM does it in Windows

Comment: thank you for updating with the non-beta edit...I probably wouldn't have thought to do that. :)

Comment: I usually try to update answers that were useful to me - in this case there was an up-vote that made it visible :)

Comment: can you take a look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229091/32012)? I've just created a `uget` tag on U&L :)

Answer (score 1):

To get a multi-threaded downloader which integrates with FlashGot, you can install `uget` and `aria2`

```
sudo apt-get install uget aria2
```

Then, go to uGet's settings and enable the aria2 plugin.

uGet will also show up on FlashGot's list, where it can be selected for browser integration.

Comment: OP has already said `aria2` is not what they want: http://askubuntu.com/questions/556991/is-it-possible-to-have-multi-thread-curl-with-flashgot-in-ubuntu#comment765265_556991

Comment: @muru -i should have made that clearer in the question maybe

Comment: take a look at Michaell Tunnell's answer, curl has multi-thread option in uGet