# the advanced browser integration doesn't work

Tags: idm

i installed IDM with wine but when i tried to use integration an error showed up as in the pic

[image: error]

Comment: Have you installed Windows browsers in Wine too?

Comment: only firefox and chromium

Comment: You installed those using Wine?

Comment: no firefox came with ubuntu and installed chromium from store.ubuntu

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/557139/47206

Answer (score 0):

Wine doesn't integrate with Ubuntu's default applications. You need special setups for that which is not fault proof.

You should install Windows browsers in Wine to get the IDM integration work. Install Chrome or Firefox using Wine and try the IDM integration then.